# SQL like in different DBMS

Tags: sql, sqlite, postgresql

I am performing a simple like query such as

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%searchterm%';
```

on the same data imported to a SQLite DB and a Postgres DB.

However, the number of results varies between the two databases.
I tried googling but I couldn't really find out if there any major implementation differences.

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: @Tichodroma the data I am working with contains around 100,000 records, thats why I asked a more general question

Comment: Then please find a small sample that can be used to reproduce the observed behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, 'cos the answer really could be as simple as "different data".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main differences you'll find is that Postgres `LIKE` queries are case-sensitive, while Sqlite isn't (at least for ASCII characters). You'll need to use `ILIKE` to get a case-insensitive match in Postgres.

Comment: Thanks, that was the reason for a differnet number of results